# WordPress upload image and media via XMLRPC

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media, xml-rpc

I want to upload some media and images to my WordPress site via XML-RPC
I used this code for this pupose:

```
$filename = 'sample.jpg';
$mime = 'images/jpeg';
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
var_dump($wpClient->uploadFile($filename, $mime, $data, false));
```

The file uploads to the media and I get this output for that:

```
array(13) {
  ["attachment_id"]=>
  string(4) "7430"
  ["date_created_gmt"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["scalar"]=>
    string(17) "20160727T19:57:29"
    ["xmlrpc_type"]=>
    string(8) "datetime"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(1469649449)
  }
  ["parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["link"]=>
  string(56) "http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/sample.jpg"
  ["title"]=>
  string(10) "sample.jpg"
  ["caption"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["metadata"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["type"]=>
  string(11) "images/jpeg"
  ["thumbnail"]=>
  string(56) "http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/sample.jpg"
  ["id"]=>
  string(4) "7430"
  ["file"]=>
  string(10) "sample.jpg"
  ["url"]=>
  string(56) "http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/sample.jpg"
}
```

But uploaded file doesn't have any title or description, How can I submit such things for that?

Comment: What's your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way myself,
After uploading the file, We should edit the post and modify those metas